# Where to put ORDER BY in this MySQL statement in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Where do I put ORDER BY `weight_record.date` in this statement to `fetchall()` into an array sorted by earliest date to latest?

```
mycursor.execute(
"SELECT weight_record.date AS wr_date, 
weight_record.weight AS wr_weight, 
calorie_record.calories AS cr_calories 
FROM weight_record 
JOIN calorie_record ON weight_record.date = calorie_record.date 
WHERE weight_record.username = %s 
AND calorie_record.username = %s", (user, user))
```

Thank you.

Comment: At the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), `ORDER BY` should come after the `WHERE` clause.